# Are there any ways to copy gestures in SwiftUI or handle them and pass them down to child views?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture

I have two TextEditors next to each other and I want to synchronize their scroll state, for example, if I scroll on the left one, the right one should show the same.

```
//basic code
@State private var textLeft: String = "view left"
@State private var textRight: String = "view right"

var body: some View {
    HStack() {
        TextEditor(text: $textLeft)
        TextEditor(text: $textLeft)
        .gesture(DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
             .updating($gestureState, body: { (value, state, transaction) in
                  print(value.translation)
             })
             .onChanged { value in
                  //this blocks the TextEditor to scroll
                  //or won't be called if the gesture is handled by the editor
                  //
                  //if I apply the offset to the other Editor 
                  //it results in weird looking behavior 
                  print(offset)
             }
         )
    }
}
```

I tried several things like applying a gesture to it and capture the movement and set it to the other as an *.offset(value)*, but either the DragGesture blocks the TextEditor or the TextEditor blocks the DragGesture.

Are there any approaches like *copying gestures* and apply them to another view or pass through the .gesture() to the view itself?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try extracting the Gesture to a computed property:

```
var dragGesture: some Gesture {
    DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
        .updating($gestureState) { value, state, transaction in
            print(value.translation)
        }
        .onChanged { value in
            // this blocks the TextEditor to scroll
            // or won't be called if the gesture is handled by the editor
            //
            // if I apply the offset to the other Editor
            // it results in weird looking behavior
            print(offset)
        }
}
```

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        TextEditor(text: $textLeft)
            .gesture(dragGesture)
        TextEditor(text: $textLeft)
            .gesture(dragGesture)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it does not change the old behavour :(

Comment: @DominikNöth Please show the code in `onChanged` as well.